# Python Selenium not able to collect element using xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Here is my Python code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.immoweb.be")
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text('FRANCAIS')
elem1.click()
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Maisons')
elem2.click()
time.sleep(2)
#searchBar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="localisation"]')
searchBar = driver.find_element_by_name('localisation')
searchbar.send_keys('hello')
```

I would like to add text in the "localisation" field, but I got the following error message.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="localisation"]"}
```

I tried the exact same code on other website, and it is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "localisation" input lives under an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), that's why you're not able to locate it

[image]

You will need to call [WebDriver.switch_to()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) function in order to change the context to the aforementioned iframe prior to attempting interacting elements inside it.

```
driver.switch_to.frame("IWEB_IFRAME_ID_SEARCH")
```

Also consider refactoring your code to remove `sleep` and use [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) instead, it will make your test much faster, robust and reliable. Moreover, some elements are being loaded using [AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) therefore they might not be immediately available even if Selenium "thinks" that the page loading is complete.

Suggested code amendments:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.immoweb.be")
elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "FRANCAIS")))
elem1.click()
elem2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Maisons")))
elem2.click()


driver.switch_to.frame("IWEB_IFRAME_ID_SEARCH")
searchBar = elem2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "localisation")))
searchBar.send_keys('hello')
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the `localisation` field as the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    # chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.immoweb.be")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "FRANCAIS"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Maisons"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#IWEB_IFRAME_ID_SEARCH")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#localisation"))).send_keys('Henri')
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Henri]

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)